# Providing a grading for the polynomial ring over a commutative unital graded ring

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, graded-rings-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative unital $G$-graded ring , where $G$ is a monoid ; then does there exist a $G$-grading on $R[X]$ such that whenever we have a commutative unital $G$-graded ring $S$ , $a \in S$ and a graded homomorphism $\phi : R \to S$ , then there exists a graded homomorphism $\bar \phi : R[X]\to S$ such that $\bar \phi |_{R}=\phi$ and $\bar \phi (X)=a$ ? If this cannot always be done , then what if we took $a\in S$ to be a homogenous element ? If even this cannot always be done ; then is there any condition on the monoid $G$ such that this type of grading can be done for any $G$-graded ring ?

Comment: The way it's stated now, it's obviously false. If $a \neq 0$ is homogeneous of degree $g \in G$, then $X$ has to have a component of degree $g$. But this is only true for finitely many $g$. However, it should be possible if you fix the homogeneous degree of $X$ a priori (hence that of $a$ as well).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn : you are right ; the homogenous degree of $X$ should be fixed a priori ; thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is only about the case where $G$ is a (commutative) *group.* I have not thought about more general monoids yet.

As observed by Remy in his comment, one has to choose $X$ to be *homogeneous of some fixed degree* and $a$ to be *homogeneous* as well. Then, this is indeed possible for polynomial algebras with an arbitrary set of indeterminates, or even more generally for algebras of monoids. For details you may have a look at paragraph 2.1.6 in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2013.06.003) (or [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.1983) for free).

Comment: could you please also take a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331462/on-giving-a-certain-kind-of-grading-to-the-polynomial-ring-over-a-commutative-un ?

Comment: Dear @users, the above also answers your question on MSE. The _original_ version of that question (about a Graded Basis Theorem) is answered in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s13366-013-0138-6) (or [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1659) for free).